# Request attribute appears to b null in the servlet

Tags: jsp, request

I have added an attribute in jsp file and try to get it in a servlet but I get null pointer exception, meaning there is no such attribute.

In jsp file:

```
  <% String p="signUp.jsp"; request.setAttribute("referredFrom",p);  %>
```

In servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        if(req.getAttribute("referredFrom").equals("signUp.jsp")){
            RequestDispatcher rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("ApplicantProfile.jsp");
            rd.forward(req,resp);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is giving null becuase you misunderstood how request works.
Lets assume that your page is `index.jsp` in path `/MyApp`.When you visit this to this page,the request is send to server.This `request` is destroyed as soon as your jsp file is loaded completely.So when you are setting attribute to this request by `request.setAttribute()`,you are setting the attribute on on the request which will be destroyed as soon as this jsp page is loaded.
Better set attribute in session and then retrive it later

```
session.setAttribute("myAttribute",myObj);
```

Retrieve it later in Servlet

```
request.getSession().getAttribute();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: the syntax  for getting attribute is getAttribute("attribute name");